# Html5 tags and headings

Tags: html

I've created this structure:

```
<header>
  <h1>page name</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Latest Articles</h1>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>Article heading</h1>
      <time>25.5.2020</time>
    </header>
    <p>article content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>Article heading</h1>
      <time>25.5.2020</time>
    </header>
    <p>article content</p>
  </article>
</main>
<section>
  <h1>Most active users</h1>
  some content here
</section>
<section>
  <h1>latest forum post</h1>
  content here
</section>
<footer>
  copyright and bullshits
</footer>
```

And I wanna ask if whole code is good structured. If I used all of html5 tags in right way and so as its headings. Thanks a lot for a response.

Answer (score 1):

The structure seems fine. However, keep in mind that there are several different "guidelines" to follow, i.e your page will still display in different browsers as long as you are implementing the HTML tags in a correct way (correct tags, not structure).
I would say there isn't really a standard way that you should write HTML in, but you should definitely comply to W3C standards (since browsers generally comply to these standards too).

Test your html through the W3C free validation service online, if that passes, then the rest is just "common practices" and a personal opinion on how you want to organize things.

[W3C Markup Validation](https://validator.w3.org/)

Cheers